# Dataview does not contains record in other event. 

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have defined dataview globally at Global declaration section. Now i am assigned the value of another dataview to that global defined dataview in one method. Now i am using that global defined Dataview into another method. But i am not getting the records that are defines in first method. I need it. How to do that?

```
public partial class Properties : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //Declaration of Dataview :
     DataView dtViewLink = new DataView();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    // define in this method 
    protected void myMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtViewLink = null;
        dtViewLink = dvEmployee;       //dvEmployee is other Dataview that has two records.
    }
    // i am using it here
   protected void ddlSortSortBy_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (dtViewLink.Count > 0)
       {
                   dtViewLink.Sort = "" + strName + " Asc";

       }
   }
}
```

That example will clear what i have to do

Comment: Are you calling the methods from the same page/lifecycle?

Comment: Please provide some sample code, so that we give you a better help.

Comment: Are you applying any filters to the local DataView which gives zero records as result ?

Comment: That does not show where you are calling myMethod()

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you  are calling the methods from  different pages or at different stage of the page lifecycle, the scope of the dataview will be lost. You should look to store this object in the cache for use on seperate pages.

Comment: It might be wise to add some code. It is likely still the same issue, variable out of scope unless you are setting the variable and then calling it within a single request. If you are setting the variable in page_load and then trying to access in a postback, it will not be saved during this transition and this is where you should look to store in some form of cache.

Comment: yes Chris ..you are right... there is the post back so data is not coming...gr8 thanks..

Answer (score 1):

put this code:

```
dtViewLink = null;
dtViewLink = dvEmployee;
```

in the PageLoad event and debug what happens in every of the methods you have shown above.

is the `dvEmployee` having any records or is it null at the following postbacks right before you enter in the method `ddlSortSortBy_SelectedIndexChanged`?

People asked you if you are in the same page lifecycle not in the same page, these two concepts are different and since web forms are stateless you should persist your data if you want to use it again in following post backs/life cycles and from other methods...

you can create your loadData event and call it from PageLoad all the times or you persist something either in the ViewState, Session or Cache depending if this same data must be available only for this page and is very small (ViewState), everywhere for the current user session (Session) or everywhere and to everybody in the web application (Cache)...

Comment: Hi Davide..you are talking exactly right.. there is problem with postback, so data is not coming.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
use 

static DataView dtViewLink ; // globally
```